# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Soy nuevo en esto, llevo ya unos dias intentanto agregar datos a dos tablas que estan relacionadas entre si.

Sin embargo, no comprendo exactamente como tener la base de datos para que puede recibir los datos que se le estan asignando mediante el medido POST al insertar.

Tengo dudas sobre la forma en que funciona el select en el formulario y la manera en que este deberia de almacenar los datos, si la tabla esta relacionada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**AgregarModal.php**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addnew" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <center><h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agregar Nuevo Registro</h4></center>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <form method="POST" action="AgregarNuevo.php">
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label class="control-label" style="position:relative; top:7px;">Nombres:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombres">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label class="control-label" style="position:relative; top:7px;">Apellidos:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label class="control-label" style="position:relative; top:7px;">Tipo Documento:</label>
                        <select class="form-select" name="Tipo_Doc" aria-label="Default select example">
                            <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                            <option value="CC">CC</option>
                            <option value="TI">TI</option>
                            <option value="CE">CE</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label class="control-label" style="position:relative; top:7px;">Num_Doc:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numero_documento">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label class="control-label" style="position:relative; top:7px;">Cargo:</label>
                        <select class="form-select" name="cargo" aria-label="Default select example">
                            <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                            <option value="Aprendiz">Aprendiz</option>
                            <option value="Instructor">Instructor</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label class="control-label" style="position:relative; top:7px;">Correo:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="correo">
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php 
                date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
                $fecha_ingreso=date("Y-m-d");
                $hora_ingreso=date("H:i:s");
                $fecha_salida=date("Y-m-d");
                $hora_salida=date("H:i:s");
            ?>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label class="control-label" style="position:relative; top:7px;">Fecha:<input type="datatime" class="form-control" name="fecha_ingreso" value="<?= $fecha_ingreso ?>" readOnly></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label class="control-label" style="position:relative; top:7px;">Hora:<input type="datatime" class="form-control" name="hora_ingreso" value="<?= $hora_ingreso ?>" readOnly></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label class="control-label" style="position:relative; top:7px;">Observacion:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="observacion">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label class="control-label" style="position:relative; top:7px;">Objeto:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="objeto">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancelar</button>
            <button type="submit" name="agregar" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Guardar Registro</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**AgregarNuevo.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();include_once('dbconect.php'); 
if(isset($_POST['agregar'])){
$fecha_ingreso=$_POST['fecha_ingreso'];
$hora_ingreso=$_POST['hora_ingreso'];
$database = new Connection();
$db = $database->open();
try{
    //hacer uso de una declaración preparada para prevenir la inyección de sql
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO registros (Nombre, Apellido, Tipo_Doc, Num_Doc, Cargo, Correo, contra_usuario) VALUES (:nombre, :apellido, :tipo_Doc, :num_Doc, :cargo, :correo, :contra_usuario)");
    

    //instrucción if-else en la ejecución de nuestra declaración preparada
    $_SESSION['message'] = ( $stmt->execute(array(':nombre' => $_POST['nombres'] , ':apellido' => $_POST['apellidos'], ':Tipo_Doc' => $_POST['Tipo_Doc'], ':Num_Doc' => $_POST['numero_documento'], ':cargo' => $_POST['cargo'], ':correo' => $_POST['correo'], ':contra_usuario' => $_POST['contraseña'])) ) ? 'Empleado guardado correctamente' : 'Algo salió mal. No se puede agregar miembro';    
    
    $tmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO info (fecha_ingreso, hora_ingreso, Observacion, Objeto) VALUES (:fecha_ingreso, :hora_ingreso, :observacion, :objeto)");
    $_SESSION['message'] = ( $tmt->execute(array(':fecha_ingreso' => $_POST['fecha_ingreso'] , ':hora_ingreso' => $_POST['hora_ingreso'], ':observacion' => $_POST['observacion'], ':objeto' => $_POST['objeto'])) ) ? 'Empleado guardado correctamente' : 'Algo salió mal. No se puede agregar miembro';    

}
catch(PDOException $e){
    $_SESSION['message'] = $e->getMessage();
}

//cerrar la conexion
$database->close();
}else{
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Llene el formulario';
}
    header('location: tables.php');
?>
```

**dbconect.php**

```
<?php

Class Connection{

private $server = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dudas";
private $username = "root";
private $password = "";
private $options  = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,);
protected $conn;

public function open(){
    try{
        $this->conn = new PDO($this->server, $this->username, $this->password, $this->options);
        //echo "Conexión Exitosaaa: " ;
        return $this->conn;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
        echo "Hubo un problema con la conexión: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

}

    public function close(){
        $this->conn = null;
    }

}

?>
```

**Base de Datos**

name=dudas

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.2.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: localhost
-- Tiempo de generación: 21-10-2022 a las 19:16:55
-- Versión del servidor: 10.4.21-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 7.4.29

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `dudas`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `info`
--

CREATE TABLE `info` (
  `id_info` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `info_vigilante` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_ingreso` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `hora_ingreso` time NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `fecha_salida` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `hora_salida` time NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `Observacion` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `Objeto` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `item_cargo`
--

CREATE TABLE `item_cargo` (
  `id_cargo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre_cargo` varchar(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `item_cargo`
--

INSERT INTO `item_cargo` (`id_cargo`, `Nombre_cargo`) VALUES
(3, 'admin'),
(4, 'user');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `item_doc`
--

CREATE TABLE `item_doc` (
  `id_doc` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre_doc` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `item_doc`
--

INSERT INTO `item_doc` (`id_doc`, `Nombre_doc`) VALUES
(1, 'CC'),
(2, 'TI');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `registros`
--

CREATE TABLE `registros` (
  `id_reg` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Apellido` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Tipo_Doc` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Num_Doc` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `Cargo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Correo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contra_usuario` varchar(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `registros`
--

INSERT INTO `registros` (`id_reg`, `Nombre`, `Apellido`, `Tipo_Doc`, `Num_Doc`, 
`Cargo`, `Correo`, `contra_usuario`) VALUES
(1, 'Nafer', 'Montañez', 2, 1044607232, 3, 'naferjml@gmail.com', '1044607232'),
(2, 'Elias', 'Padilla', 1, 13090192, 3, 'elias@gmail.com', '1234');

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `info`
--
ALTER TABLE `info`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_info`),
  ADD KEY `info_vigilante` (`info_vigilante`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `item_cargo`
--
ALTER TABLE `item_cargo`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_cargo`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `item_doc`
--
ALTER TABLE `item_doc`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_doc`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `registros`
--
ALTER TABLE `registros`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_reg`),
  ADD KEY `Tipo_Doc` (`Tipo_Doc`),
  ADD KEY `Cargo` (`Cargo`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `info`
--
ALTER TABLE `info`
  MODIFY `id_info` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `item_cargo`
--
ALTER TABLE `item_cargo`
  MODIFY `id_cargo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `item_doc`
--
ALTER TABLE `item_doc`
  MODIFY `id_doc` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `registros`
--
ALTER TABLE `registros`
  MODIFY `id_reg` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `info`
--
ALTER TABLE `info`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `info_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`info_vigilante`) REFERENCES `registros` 
(`id_reg`);

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `registros`
--
ALTER TABLE `registros`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `registros_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Cargo`) REFERENCES 
`item_cargo` 
    (`id_cargo`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `registros_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Tipo_Doc`) REFERENCES 
`item_doc` 
    (`id_doc`);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pienso que posiblemente la base de datos no corresponde a los valores que se le estan agregan por lo que necesita cambios o cambiar la forma en que se envian los datos a ella, mi problema es que no tengo sufuciente experiencia como para saber exactamente que cambios se necesitan, las relaciones necesarias entre tablas y la manera en que se envian los datos.

Agredeceria muchísimo si alguien me da un consejo de como debo de tener la base de datos al ingresar una fecha "automatica", si la forma en que se envian los datos de los select a la base de datos corresponde... o al realizar consultas.

En resumen, señalar todo tipo de errores de hay tanto como puede ser en el código como en la base de datos.

Comment: Resulta un poco confuso tu cuestionamiento y aparenta abarcar varias cuestiones. Trata de leerte algo por internet, ej mysqltutorials o geeksforgeeks y esos que están orientados a novatos y son bien claros y así comprender qué necesitas para poder plantear tu problema bien concreto y con claridad.

Comment: El problema son las diferencias en los nombres de los marcadores. Ejemplo: En la sentencia usas `:tipo_Doc` pero al enviar los datos usas `:Tipo_Doc`. También pasó con `Num_Doc`